# Django HTTP Redirect outside of view function

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-2.6

Is there a way to redirect to another page in Django when outside of a view function.

I need to be able to redirect anywhere in my app, NOT just when I'm returning an HTTP response back to the client.

I've tried the redirect shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
redirect("/some/url")
```

and also

```
redirect("http://someserver.com/some/url")
```

but this does no noticable action.

I need something like `header("Location: /some/url");` in PHP which can be used anywhere inside the script.

Thanks

Comment: Redirection cannot be done outside a view function I think.

Comment: View methods are trigged when a request is mapped to them, that's when the execute. If you don't request anything (that is, don't click a link or load a page), view functions don't execute - so it doesn't make sense to redirect anything outside of a view function. What actually are you trying to do?

Comment: The user has clicked a link and a view function is executing, but that view function calls another library (a standard view controller implementation) which fills the template and contains various logic which may require a redirect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could abuse/leverage `process_exception` of middleware:

```
# middleware.py
from django import shortcuts

class Redirect(Exception):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

def redirect(url):
    raise Redirect(url):

class RedirectMiddleware:
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, Redirect):
            return shortcuts.redirect(exception.url)
```

You can then do:

```
from middleware import redirect
redirect('/some/url/')
```

Also don't forget to add `RedirectMiddleware` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` settings.

Comment: This was helpful, but it's worth adding that you need to add the RedirectMiddleware class to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES settings.

'appname.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',

Comment: Hi Jesse, I know this is super old, but the answer still seems to be relevant, so I was wondering why you refer to this as "abuse" of the `process_exception` middleware function? It seems to me that this is exactly the kind of application that it was intended for. Just wondering if I'm missing something here.

Comment: Hey @zelanix, I came across this by pure coincidence! I guess the implication is the questionability of using exceptions for control flow (rather than handling errors and anomalies). This is far more common and acceptable in python than most other programming languages, so I don't think you're really missing anything. I'll update the answer!