# How to use django.shortcuts.redirect outside the view function?

Tags: python, django

I am making a STT app on my website which uses openai-whisper.

---

#### repo in need

> https://github.com/AkioKiyota/arge-test

## General Purpose

> Giving users a display/feedback about the process, and running a process without intervening the page.

### Working steps are like this:

- You upload your mp4-mp3 file throught form,
- You click the STT button next to your audio-clip-name,
- It downloads the whisper model(small), which happens once,
- Whisper transcribes the mp3 throught its path,
- Returns the result.

> Just ignore the div says 'last speech to text' its normaly where it should be showing it.

[image]

[image]

---

### Current script

#### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import AudioStoreForm
from .models import AudioStore

import whisper

def index(request):

    audios = AudioStore.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AudioStoreForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        form = AudioStoreForm()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form, 'audios': audios})

def stt(request, audio_name):
    module = whisper.load_model('small')
    audio = AudioStore.objects.get(name=audio_name)
    result = module.transcribe(audio.audio_file.path, verbose=False)

    return HttpResponse(result['text'])
```

---

### The Issue

The problem is, page just keep loading while the transribe on the process. But i *atleast* want to add a reloading icon to show user that its actualy working and he should wait. I have tried using Threads like this:

#### views.py

```
def stt_thread(request, model, path):
    print('stt_thread')
    result = model.transcribe(path, verbose=False)
    print('transcribe done')
    return redirect('/?result=' + result['text'])

def stt(request, audio_name):
    audio = AudioStore.objects.get(name=audio_name)
    path = audio.audio_file.path
    model = whisper.load_model('small')

    result = threading.Thread(target=lambda: stt_thread(request, model, path))
    result.start()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/?pending=True')
```

Which is kinda worked, but it just stuck on the pending. It didn't loaded the result result even if the result is given on the console.

> I also tried this [Django HTTP Redirect outside of view function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677159/django-http-redirect-outside-of-view-function)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't make an additional redirect, your view returns a redirect response, and the view is done, the fact that some other thread runs and return something is irrelevant. Typically what is done is the response passes a task id, and then the frontend has some JavaScript that polls the task every now and then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect is act of returning a special response to client browser, ending a (sync) request-response cycle. You have no code that returns a redirect from thread to browser.
Basically you are facing an XY problem, and also I'm not sure what you mean by showing a "reloading icon"

You have a long-running process and don't want client to wait on "loading page" (it's loading because browser is waiting for response). And if process is more then ~20seconds you rather can't let client wait, normally connections are terminated if they are longer. I don't see how redirects may help here.

You either use a different web technology that allows continuous connection, or if you stick to simpler solutions - let the task run in the background, and close connection with client letting it know that result will come later.

It could be a waiting page with task id which user can reload manually to check if it's done or have a script that polls asynchronously for it, or some other solution if it fits better your case.

Also using threading here is as well likely a wrong pick, because I'm not sure when it thread might be killed, since server worker is not guaranteed to keep running between request-response cycle. Usually background tasks are done with separate tool, like Celery for example, or you could explore a number of it's alternative task managers.

Comment: thanks for your advice i will update the website as you said and learn how to do it with javascript :D